# Which of the license is used by SaaJ-api ? CDDL or GPL?

Tags: gpl, license, cddl

I am looking at 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/saaj-api

It mentions 2 licenses:
CDDL and GPL.

Does it mean it uses both licenses ? or any one of them ? If just one of them how to know which one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SaaJ-api package is dual-licensed under both the CDDL and the GPL with Classpath Exception. This dual licensing means that you, as user of the package, can choose which license terms you want to comply with, either the CDDL or the GPL.

Comment: what is the Classpath exception

Comment: @JavaDeveloper the Classpath Exception is a special permission that is granted on top of the GPL license which effectively states that you can ignore the requirements from the GPL if you use a package/class file with that exception only through the Java Classpath.